# How does Python handle checking 'if object in list'

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, list

I'm wondering because I need to have have a function that is disgustingly fast at checking if a word is in a dictionary list - I'm considering leaving the dictionary as a large string and running regex against instead. This needs to be absurdly fast. So I just need a basic overview of *how* python handles checking if a string is in a list of strings and if its beyond-reasonable fast.

Comment: Why not use a `set` of words for this dictionary instead of a `list`?  Also, are you familiar with `timeit` which will allow you to gather actual benchmarks instead of hypotheticals?

Comment: I briefly saw it while thinking of benchmarking but haven't had a shot to actually use it to test the speeds. I've been attacking more obvious speed issues for now. Suggestion for tutorial or something?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html.

Comment: `word in string` will be a little faster than `word in list` and at least as fast as a compiled regular expression because unless the list is sorted in some way (a hashtable is an example), there __is__ no faster way.

Comment: `word in string` may be a bit faster in practice due to careful optimization, but it's actually a notably more complex operation, as it's a substring search.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want a blazingly fast membership test, then a list is the wrong data structure. Take a look at the implementation of `list_contains` in [`listobject.c`, line 437](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b754641a429f/Objects/listobject.c#l437). It iterates over the list in order, comparing the item with each element in turn. The later the item appears in the list, the longer it will take to find it, and if the item is missing, then the whole list must be scanned.

Use a [set](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) instead. Sets are implemented internally by a hash table, so looking up an object involves computing its hash and then scanning a few table entries (usually just one). For the particular case of looking up a string, see `set_lookkey_string` in [`setobject.c`, line 156](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b754641a429f/Objects/setobject.c#l156).

Comment: I redact my previous statement, using a set - but why is a set faster for searching if 'in'?

Comment: @jphenow: Sets use a hash, not a linear search.

Comment: Nice edit, fantastically described. Well that saves me a bunch of work, but now I'll be hard pressed to find a great way to really speed this thing up :)

Comment: Just make sure that the hash has good distribution... too many collisions and you are back to linear search.

Comment: @Bruno: The hashes of strings and integers (and probably more, e.g. tuples of ints/strings) have distributions that are "predictable" at best. Python dicts using those still perform superb because the gods who brought us `dictobject` have crafted algorithms which don't give a damn about the distribution as long as the hashes aren't all equal. Even if they share all lower bits, you only have a handful of lookups until the higher bits are taken into account. Read the source, it's fascinating. Plus, none of this is your concern if you don't write your own hashable types.

Answer (score 4):

A set of strings will have O(1) lookup time: effectively constant regardless of the size of the set.  Making a set from your list of strings is easy:

```
my_set = set(my_list)
if my_word in my_set:
    print "it's there!"
```

Comment: So basicly you are saying that checking a occurence in a set with 1 item is just as fast as in one with 1000000? Bullshit. Any sort of lookup with random data is at least `log n`.

Comment: @nightcracker: Sets are implemented by hash tables, so Ned is quite right.

Comment: @nightcracker: you might want to learn about how hash tables work before throwing around strong words.  Also: http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: @nightcracker: odd: you suggested the very same thing, with a link to the Wikipedia article about hash algorithms.  Perhaps read it?

Comment: Sure, the __average__ time is constant, but the worst-case example is still O(n).

Comment: @nightcracker: Yeah, it's *amortized* O(1). But that's just nitpicking, as the "amortized" stands for "unless you are tailoring data specifically to make this algorithm look bad, conducting flawed micro-benchmarks and project the results, or having *really* bad luck with your real-world data, it will work about this well for any significant data set". I.e. yeah, lookup in a 1000000 element set can be as fast as lookup in a singleton set, or similar enough to make the difference invisible to everyone but a microbenchmark.

Comment: I'd say the typical and expected time is constant.  "Average" is an ambiguous term unfortunately.  The worst case is in fact O(n), but that's the pathological case of every element in the set having an identical hash.  In practice, looking up data in a set takes the same time irrespective of the size of the set.  Certainly "log n" has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

If you need real fast checking, use a [`set`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
words = set(words_list)
if "hello" in words:
    print("hello found!"")
```

A set is faster because it uses a [hash-algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function), instead of a direct search approach.

Comment: See comment for @Gareth, I am now using a set instead, but why would set search faster?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this site](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), `x in s` is O(n).  Therefore, it checks each entry (in the worst case).

At any rate, do not use a regex.  Using sets or lists is a much more intuitive way to represent the data and regexes will not perform better than O(n).

Comment: And according to [the CPython source](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Objects/listobject.c?view=markup#l438) it definitely checks each entry :)

Comment: Ah good call, I suppose I'm not partial to regex, moreso just seeking out the quickest way to get through the words, efficiently.

Comment: It checks each entry *in the worst case* (no matching item or only the last item matching). That's a difference, although not a large one given the availability of an O(1) solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a regular list, consider a [`set`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set) instead.

If you want to implement your own fine-tuned membership test for your container object,  override [`__contains__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__).

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a Set if you're worried about time. A Set is much like a list, but it checks for membership based on hashing.

Answer (score 0):

Use a set.
If you need case-insensitive checking, just store the words into the set downcased. Then when checking if a certain word is in the set, downcase the word before checking membership.

The general rule is: normalize entries when building the set, and normalize an item before checking against the set. Another example of normalization is collapsing consecutive whitespace chars into a single space and stripping leading/trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Running a regex against your word list is a very bad idea; it scales very badly.
Using `dict()`, `set()` or `frozenset()` will scale a lot better:

```
s = set(['one','two','three'])
'two' in s     ## true

b='four'
b in s         ## false

s.add('four')
b in s         ## true
```